# Running a program that has no extension

Tags: installation, command-line

I was given a program to run on my machine....the file is just the name of the program with no extension. There wasn't very many instructions, all that was included was commands I could type...one of them was

programname -h

Doing this would supposedly give me more instructions on what to do...but how do I run a program so I can do this. I have working knowledge of linux, but not a whole lot dealing with program installations, so pardon if this is a noob question answered elsewhere (I did a search but couldn't find a match).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chmod +x

execute the program

ex:

program name is "test". It is located at /home/user1/Downloads/test

cd /home/user1/Downloads/

chmod +x ./test

./test -h